# How Can I Expose Private Fields using a Partial Class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, transactions, dataset, partial-classes, dataadapter

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so please exuse (and feel free to point out) any n00b mistakes.

I am trying to implement transactions across multiple TableAdapters in VB.NET (using Visual Studio 2010) by extending the partial class as described in the following examples:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/06/18/the-definitive-tableadapters--transactions-blog-post.aspx

madprops.org/blog/typed-datasets-and-sqltransaction/

stackoverflow.com/questions/2342289/net-tableadapter-to-dataadapter

However, when I attempt to expose any of the private fields created by the designer they are underlined in the editor with the following error:

> '_adapter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
>   level.

Searching this site as well as google has not revealed anything useful, but perhpas I'm searching the wrong keywords.

Here is the code in MyDataset.vb

```
Partial Public Class MyTableAdapter
    Public Property MyTransaction() As SqlTransaction
        Get
            Return _adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SqlTransaction)
            If _adapter Is Nothing Then
                InitAdapter()
            End If
            Connection = value.Connection
            _adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = value
            _adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = value
            _adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

and here is the designer code:

```
Partial Public Class MyTableAdapter
    Inherits Global.System.ComponentModel.Component

    Private WithEvents _adapter As Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Private _connection As Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Private _transaction As Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction
    Private _commandCollection() As Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
```

Am I missing something, or is this not possible in VB (all of the examples I've seen are in C#)?

TIA for any help!

JE

Comment: Do the namespace names match?

Comment: No they didn't, and this was in fact the problem.  The designer inserted the fully qualified namespace but it should only be MyDatasetTableAdapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you access any Public properties/methods from the Adapter class?

I think you may have created your partial class in the wrong namespace. It has to be in `Namespace MyDataSetTableAdapters`

Comment: Thank you Henk!  The designer inserted the fully qualified Namespace but changing it to only MyDatasetTableAdapters fixed the problem!

Comment: How can I accept your answer?  I can't up-vote b/c I'm a n00b :-)

Comment: ...duh, I guess that's what the giant checkmark is for!  Thanks again, I was staring at this for over an hour.